# Fixing warped board pieces

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights, components

The pieces are usually kept in the box and not even used that much. However, I took them out the other day to play and all the hex pieces were warped. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to contact Mayfair Games -- doing a Google search turned up quite a few people with warped hex tiles as well, and the consensus was to contact Mayfair.

If that's a dead end, you can try flattening them with a heavy object, or glue them to some thicker cardstock.

Comment: Do you tihnk they'd replace my game or send me replacement pieces?

Comment: @MaxMackie -- I assume they'll just send replacement pieces.  If you can take pictures send them to show the warping, that would probably help your case.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. When I have a chance to (finals), I'll take some pictures and send them in.

Comment: I contacted Mayfair a week ago based on this advice. Didn't work. The response: "I am sorry but I cannot help you. The version you have is an older 3rd edition Seafarers expansion which has been discontinued since 2007 and I no longer have any replacement parts available."

Answer (score 2):

A very nice set of [laser-cut acrylic tiles](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5727) costs about $100 ("How much do you love Settlers of Catan?")

Comment: Have you used these?  How well do they work?

Comment: Note that the link is to a DIY page with files for use with a laser cutter; it's not a store price, and there aren't (yet) places where you can simply purchase this set or the [3D printer set](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5755) that may have been the inspiration for these (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks for the note, Dave. Yes, this is a set of files that can be used to cut tiles, not an actual storefront selling the tiles. I don't own a set, but I'm hoping to get them soon. When I get them, I will likely purchase them from Daniel Holmes of JNC Designs (he posted on the thingverse page) - he gave me a price of $135 for acrylic tiles, $115 for poplar wood, and $62 for MDF.

Answer (score 1):

To flatten the hexes themselves, stack them and bind them tightly with rubber bands in all 3 directions across the six sides.

To avoid the problem of the warped hexes entirely: get a sheet of clear acrylic that is big enough to cover the whole board and border.  You could cut it to fit, cut it to fit and in halves for portability, or leave it square/rectangular.  Place the sheet over the assembled board and play on the perfect resulting surface! It will flatten the hexes while you play, but I'd just keep a right-sized sheet with the game.

Comment: If you use it, let me know how it works out for you, hey?

Comment: Sure, but I'd have to get my hands on some acrylic and get it shaped for me. Unfortunately the local hardware store is incompetent and will only cut in squares or rectangles (I know this from personal experience)